# karate - How to change display name of a Feature file in the report

Tags: karate

I am using net.masterthought for reporting purpose. however under Feature name, it displayed the complete relative path. Here I want just to display feature file name.

Below the code.

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:demo").outputCucumberJson(true).parallel(0);
Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(results.getReportDir()), new String[] {"json"}, true);
List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Demo Project");
ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
reportBuilder.generateReports();
```

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: assume that this is not supported. contribute code, write your own report or use another framework if needed